# Multilanguage site in Codeigniter

Tags: url, codeigniter, multilingual

I'm starting a new site project in Codeigniter. I need this site to be multilingual, where English will be the default language. 
I know how the language  class in codeigniter works, and I am already using it.

My concern is that I need the URL to be shown in the selected language. I'll explain myself with an example:

When **English** language is selected, I have this URL:
    **www.domain.com/cars/list_cars**
where **cars** is the controller and **list_cars** is the method in charge of calling the appropriate view.

When **Spanish** language language is selected, I would like the URL to show as
    **www.domain.com/coches/mostrar_coches**

Which is the best way to achieve this? The only way I can think of is by changing **routes.php** with something like:

```
$route['cars/list_cars'] = 'coches/mostrar_coches';
```

Is there any better/easier way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what you propose, using routes.php for your localised url segments. Works fine for me but for every page you do need a new entry in your routes file.

Comment: having an entry in routes.php for each page is what puts me off, but I suppose it is the only way around to do it.
Codeigniter needs to know what you want to translate the name page to, and in this situation I cant use a regexp.

Answer (score 2):

I built the [concebe.com](http://concebe.com) with CodeIgniter and Url translated. My solution was to redirect all requests to only one controller, which is responsible for calling other functions depending on the translation. see below:

```
function dinamic($js,$page,$item=NULL,$id=NULL)
{

    switch ($page)
    {
        case $this->lang->line('products'):
            $page='products';
        break;
        case $this->lang->line('about_us'):
            $page='about_us';
        break;
        ...
    }

    //switch page
    switch ($page)
    {
        case 'contact_us':
            $this->template->render($js,$this->_contact_us($js));
            return;
        break;
    }
```

This is not a clever solution and don't help you too, because is harder, but I have to differentiate the js call also, and this was the only way, I hope this help someone.

Constrains:when switch language, you lose the page were you where.

Answer (score 0):

Translating your controller and method names is a headache waiting to happen. The benefits to your SEO are so minimal that it is really not worth doing, just make sure you have good content.

Comment: I'm surprised of your answer. I'm not a SEO guru, but I've read many times that having keyword in your URL is one of the most important points to consider.
That is why I want to "translate" the URL.

Comment: SEO benefits would be substantial in the right circumstances. Thought needs to be put in to it.

Comment: Hey if you want to manually translate every single URL so you can have a slight SEO bump go ahead, I'd rather just make sure my content is good for each language.